# Trying to get averages from multiple columns here but all the values print as 0

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, average

Here is my code, my error is that the $result variable is expected to be an array.  But I'm not too sure how to achieve this.

```
<?php     
        $sql ="SELECT AVG(dive_rating) AS avg_rating, 
        AVG(col1) AS col1,
        AVG(col2) AS col2,
        AVG(col3) AS col3,
        AVG(col4) AS col4,
        FROM this_table WHERE col_name='$col_name'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $col1 = $row['col1'];
        $col2 = $row['col2'];
        $col3 = $row['col3'];
        $col4 = $row['col4'];
        $col5 = $row['col5'];

        echo round($col1,1);
        echo round($col2,1);
        echo round($col3,1);
        echo round($col3,1);
?>
```

Comment: I don't believe that's the error you're getting. Doesn't it say that the argument to `mysql_fetch_array` should be a resource?

Comment: Change the `$result` line to `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` so you see the error message from SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma in there, try it like this:

```
$sql ="SELECT AVG(dive_rating) AS avg_rating, 
        AVG(col1) AS col1,
        AVG(col2) AS col2,
        AVG(col3) AS col3,
        AVG(col4) AS col4
        FROM this_table WHERE col_name='$col_name'";
```